# What does "Aeroplane Mode" disable?

Tags: configuration

I have noticed that in the `gnome-control-center` when I enable `Aeroplane Mode` that Bluetooth no longer becomes an option to be turned on, though this is reversed when disabling `Aeroplane Mode`. Wifi though does not seem to be disabled with the enabling of this mode.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20 and I am just really curious, what exactly does enabling with mode disable? Is there a list of modules it blacklists or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aeroplane mode disables the Wifi (or WLan), bluetooth and Telephony (2G/3G etc) signals. This can be seen from system log. Also This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_mode) says same thing about airplane mode or Aeroplane mode -

> > When the "airplane mode" is activated, it disables all voice and text telephony and other signal-transmitting technologies such as Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

And this [Gnome Help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/net-wireless-airplane.html.en) article says, more clearly

> > Using Airplane Mode will completely turn off all wireless connections, including WiFi, 3G and Bluetooth connections.

When it's disabled I find entry in systemlog like these

```
Sep 10 16:14:13 anwar-pc NetworkManager[957]: <info>  [1473502453.7404] manager: WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
Sep 10 16:14:13 anwar-pc NetworkManager[957]: <info>  [1473502453.7616] device (20:54:76:75:5B:C6): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [30 10 36]
Sep 10 16:14:13 anwar-pc URfkill[864]: device_changed_cb: ideapad_bluetooth
Sep 10 16:14:13 anwar-pc URfkill[864]: device_changed_cb: hci0
```

When disabled, The entries are like this

```
Sep 10 16:15:31 anwar-pc NetworkManager[957]: <info>  [1473502531.8393] manager: WiFi now enabled by radio killswitch
Sep 10 16:15:31 anwar-pc systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Sep 10 16:15:31 anwar-pc systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Sep 10 16:15:31 anwar-pc URfkill[864]: device_changed_cb: ideapad_bluetooth
Sep 10 16:15:31 anwar-pc URfkill[864]: device_changed_cb: hci0
Sep 10 16:15:32 anwar-pc NetworkManager[957]: <info>  [1473502532.0363] manager: (20:54:76:75:5B:C6): new Bluetooth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/17)
```

In the first log, device `(20:54:76:75:5B:C6)` is the bluetooth device.